# cross reference style?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to put a parentheses around the crossed reference and remove the parentheses around the number of the crossed reference, as in the below image.

[image]

I used `cleveref` package, I tried this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=cyan}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{(eq.}{eqs.}        
\crefname{section}{(sec.}{secs.}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textbf{\textit{\textup{#1}}}#3)}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Math}
\section{Equation}\label{sec:equation}
\begin{align}
A =& B (C + D) \label{eq:equation 1}\\
  =& B C + B D
\end{align}
see \cref{sec:equation} and \cref{eq:equation 1}
\end{document}
```

the problem is when I refer to multi equations or multi sections, which be as:
[image]

any help with that?

Comment: Just so that I understand your objectives: Why is there a closing parenthesis, but no opening parenthesis, in the arguments of `\crefdefaultlabelformat` and `\creflabelformat{equation}`?

Comment: Please also post the code that generates the two screenshots you've posted. The color (cyan?) isn't set by `cleveref`, is it?

Comment: @Mico the opening parentheses is in `\crefname` and the closing is in `\crefdefaultlabelformat` and `\creflabelformat{equation}`, for the color it is just a test color and setting by `hypersetup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each item type to be cross-referenced -- `equation`, `section`, etc -- you need to provide `\crefmultiformat` and `\crefrangeformat` directives to state the formatting requirements explicitly. The former macro is used by the `cleveref` package to evaluate the argument of a `\cref` instruction if the argument consists of either exactly two items or if there are more than two items, with a gap somewhere in the items' numbers. The latter macro is used by `cleveref` either if the list of three or more items in the argument of `\cref` contains no gaps or if `\crefrange{first-arg}{last-arg}` is encountered.

In the example below, I show the code that's needed for `equation` items. I trust you can figure out how to provide similar instructions for `section`, `figure`, `table`, etc items.

Since you'll be providing explicit formatting instructions for single and multiple items, I would also like to suggest you drop the `\crefdefaultlabelformat` and `\creflabelformat` directives and that you use something like

```
\crefformat{equation}{(eq.~#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}
```

for each item type that needs to be cross-referenced via `\cref`.
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "gather" environment
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{(eq.~#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}
\crefmultiformat{equation}%
   {(eqs.~#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3}% % first item in list
   { and~#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}% % second (if exactly two items)
   {, #2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3}%     % middle (if more than two items)
   { and~#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}  % last   (if more than two items)
\crefrangeformat{equation}%
   {(eqs.~#3\textbf{\textup{#1}}#4 to~#5\textbf{\textup{#2}}#6)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{gather}
A = B (C + D) \label{eq:mult}  \\
e^{i\pi}-1=0  \label{eq:euler} \\
a^2+b^2=c^2   \label{eq:pyth}  \\
E = m c^2     \label{eq:einst}
\end{gather}

\cref{eq:mult,eq:pyth}                   % two items

\cref{eq:mult,eq:pyth,eq:einst}          % three items, with gap

\cref{eq:mult,eq:euler,eq:pyth,eq:einst} % four items, no gap

\crefrange{eq:mult}{eq:einst}            % explicit range of items
\end{document}
```